# I am web developer, can i use my working pc to mine and work at same time?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, development

Guyz, i am a web developer, i have single pc but i am thinking to add a good GPU in it, my question is that if i add good GPU, will i be able to mine crypto currencies like BTC/ETH and work on my pc at same time? will it be OK ? Kindly share your opinions experts. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That would be possible but probably not profitable.

If you use your GPU to mine BTC the costs for electricity are most likely higher than your gains from mining.

I don't know if GPU mining is profitable for ETH. That also depends on where you live and what you have to pay for electricity of course.